# Jquery html.() with Django, replace complete webpage periodically with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am refreshing my page via jQuery html.() using AJAX request. Currently I am working with the Django local server. My problem is that when I run periodically my AJAX request the CSS and JS files are loading one more time than the previous load. I mean the AJAX request running in every minutes. In the first minutes the static files load just once, next time twice and so on.. I do not understand this situation. Can everybody explain it?

**Here is my AJAX call:**

```
setInterval(function(){
       if(new Date().getSeconds() === 0) {
        console.log(new Date().getMinutes());
        n++
        console.log(n);
        $.ajax({
        url:'{% url 'fetch_data' %}',
        success: function (data){
                $('body').html('');
                $('body').html(data);
           }
        });
  }
},1000)
```

Comment: don't you think `$('body').html();` need to be `$('body').html(data);`

Comment: Yes this was just a type. I corrected it.

Comment: what data contains?complete page html?

Comment: what does `data` contain?

Comment: Yes. It contains the whole html.

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: you could drop the head of the loaded html, and just take the body, see my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you check what `data` contains. If it contains a complete html page, including a `head` tag, the browser might drop the `head` but keep the css and js asset (and other things that were in there), so they get loaded again. also, browser treat such anomalies different sometimes, what then could cause more headache. ideally, you'll not load css and js every minute anyway, and just reload content.

if you dont control what is in `data`, you could fetch the relevant thing like this:

```
// hopefully without js and css references
var bodyOnly = $(data).find('body').html();
$('body').html(bodyOnly)
```

if you really want your js (more difficult to impossible) and css (easier) every minute, you could try adding a timestamp querystring to the existing asset, for example `screen.css?9868768769876`.